# Events to iframe

Tags: javascript

How to assign events to iframe in javascript? Thanks in advance. I want to assign Keypress or keyup or click events.

Comment: What all events do you want to assign?

Comment: Could you explain in a little more detail?

Comment: i should mention that you can bind event handlers to the inner document of your iframe only if that document is served from the same domain as the parent window. If the iframe serves a document from a different domain you won't be able to bind anything because of the cross domain security policy.

Answer (score 1):

An iframe contains the usual `document`, `window` and `body` elements that you can assign events to. For maximum simplicity, do it inside the IFrame. Otherwise, just address the iframe from the outlying document:

```
document.getElementById("your_iframe_id"). ....
```