# calling a function in a javascript external file in a parent to an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, iframe, cross-domain

How do you call a javascript function that is in an external javascript file that was added to the parent of an iframe? I tried `parent.function()` in the iframe but that didn't work.

Comment: This is asked all the time http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900504/events-to-iframe. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893280/jquery-select-iframe-children... and many more

Comment: parent.functionName() should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

try using window.parent.document